# Scrolling mini-menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this menu and what i want is to "hide" it elements when either class a or class b length is bigger than whole container. I want similar effect like facebook has: [image] How can I achieve this effect? I'm thinking about one way that is in comment section, but I don't know what next.

```js
$('.b').hide();
     $(".a").click(function(){
        $(".b").slideToggle(200);
    });

/*
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   
    var k = $("#container").length;
 var n = $(".a").length;
    
    
 if (n > k) {
  
 } 
 else {

 }

});
*/
```

```css
#container
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

ul
{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.a
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.b
{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;  
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="a"></li>
            <ul>
                <li class="b"></li>
                <li class="b"></li>
                <li class="b"></li>
            </ul>
        <li class="a"></li>
        <li class="a"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by length is bigger?

Comment: When elements in container are longer then current container length. For example: Container has 500px and elements, when toggled down together might have around 1000px.

Comment: I really don't understand the question. Can you give an example?

Comment: I want to make vertical menu that will look like the picture i have uploaded/attached to this post. What I have for the moment is the thing i have in code snippet. The problem is how to actually make this elements "hide" when their summed length will be longer then container length. http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/397/Vertical-Scrolling-News-Ticker-With-jQuery-jCarouse Something like this but not automatically; only with "scroll" event. And i have no idea how to connect everything to one piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `overflow-y: scroll;` on `#container` and play around until it looks like you want it to look. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5zqpc42/).

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.a {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.b {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="a"></li>
        <ul>
            <li class="b"></li>
            <li class="b"></li>
            <li class="b"></li>
        </ul>
        <li class="a"></li>
        <li class="a"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So basically I don't have to use JS right? Just pure CSS. Thats nice, thanks a lot! I didnt think it would be that easy.

Comment: No JS, except if you want to make some fancy slider out of it. If it's purely to cut off the div when the content gets higher than the div's set height, use overflow.

Comment: Didn't know about this CSS function. So if i would like to make cool looking slider i have to style it with JS?

Comment: Well, we're not here to make stuff for you, we're here to help you. If you want to make it automatically scroll, I recommend google. If you can't figure it out, you're very welcome to create a new question.

Comment: No, no, no. My bad there. By cool looking slider i meant the visual look of slider. But anyway, thanks a lot for this help!